# What is the expectation of a copula function?

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions, copula

Let us say $X=(X_1,X_2)'$, where $X\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and we have a copula of the form $C(F_{X_1}(x_1),F_{X_2}(x_2))$. What would $\mathbb{E}_X\left[C(F_{X_1}(x_1),F_{X_2}(x_2))\right]$?

Comment: What is a copula?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)